# How do I correctly install dulwich to get hg-git working on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, mercurial, hg-git, dulwich

I'm trying to use the hg-git Mercurial extension on Windows (Windows 7 64-bit, to be specific). I have Mercurial and Git installed. I have Python 2.5 (32-bit) installed.

I followed the instructions on http://hg-git.github.com/ to install the extension. The initial easy_install failed because it was unable to compile dulwich without Visual Studio 2003.

I installed dulwich manually by:

- git clone git://git.samba.org/jelmer/dulwich.git
- cd dulwich
- c:\Python25\python setup.py --pure install

Now when I run easy_install hg-git, it succeeds (since the dulwich dependency is satisfied).

In my C:\Users\username\Mercurial.ini, I have:

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit =
```

When I type 'hg' at a command prompt, I see:
"*** failed to import extension hggit: No module named hggit"

Looking under my c:\Python25 folder, the only reference to hggit I see is `Lib\site-packages\hg_git-0.2.1-py2.5.egg`. Is this supposed to be extracted somewhere, or should it work as-is?

Since that failed, I attempted the "more involved" instructions from the hg-git page that suggested cloning git://github.com/schacon/hg-git.git and referencing the path in my Mercurial configuration. I cloned the repo, and changed my extensions file to look like:

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit = c:\code\hg-git\hggit
```

Now when I run hg, I see: *** failed to import extension hggit from c:\code\hg-git\hggit: No module named dulwich.errors.

Ok, so that tells me that it is finding hggit now, because I can see in hg-git\hggit\git_handler.py that it calls

```
from dulwich.errors import HangupException
```

That makes me think dulwich is not installed correctly, or not in the path.

**Update:**

From Python command line:

```
import dulwich
```

yields `Import Error: No module named dulwich`

However, under C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages, I do have a dulwich-0.5.0-py2.5.egg folder which appears to be populated. This was created by the steps mentioned above. Is there an additional step I need to take to make it part of the Python "path"?

From Python command line (as suggested in one of the answers):

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require('dulwich')
```

yields `[dulwich 0.5.0 (c:\python25\lib\site-packages\dulwich-0.5.0-py2.5.egg)]`

So what does that tell me? Importing dulwich fails, but apparently pkg_resources can find it. What can I do with that information?

Comment: In an interactive Python session, run:
{{{
>>> import dulwich
>>> print dulwich.__version__
}}}
What does that show?

Comment: Added results to the Update section above

Comment: I am assuming that you are asking about Microsoft's Window (not just any windowing system). If anyone coming to this question from Debian (or similar) then you can do `sudo apt install python-dulwich`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> That makes me think dulwich is not
>   installed correctly, or not in the
>   path.

You're absolutely right. Mercurial binary distributions for Windows are 'frozen' - they use the Python code and interpreter bundled with them and therefore independent of packages installed in system PYTHONPATH. When you specify path to hggit extension in Mercurial.ini, hg tries to import it using direct path, but dulwich library is not imported explicitly by hg and doesn't bundled with its library, so the import fails.

It is possible to add both Dulwich and HgGit into library.zip that is installed along with hg.exe, but for me the best way is to install everything from source including Mercurial and execute commands using .bat files installed into \Python\Scripts. In this case you will need to:

1. [Install Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WindowsInstall#Building_pure_Python_alternative) from source. This builds "pure" version, because Windows users usually don't have Visual Studio or alternative compiler for compiling C speedups.
2. Install Dulwich - I'd use latest trunk [snapshot](http://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/archives/master) for both Git and Dulwich.

   python setup.py --pure install
3. Install latest HgGit [snapshot](http://github.com/schacon/hg-git/archives/master)

   python setup.py install
4. Edit Mercurial.ini to enable `hggit =`
5. Launch Mercurial using your \Python\Scripts\hg.bat

Comment: What's wrong with adding Dulwich and HgGit into `library.zip`? It looks like nicer solution to me.

Comment: @Piotr: Nothing wrong except that `library.zip` is not always an ordinary archive. So you will need a script like this - http://techtonik.rainforce.org/2010/01/repacking-libraryzip-from-py2exe.html

Comment: Or if using Debian `sudo apt install python-dulwich`. (I found this is a search, but I don't use MS)

Answer (score 12):

I found a simpler solution at http://candidcode.com/2010/01/12/a-guide-to-converting-from-mercurial-hg-to-git-on-a-windows-client/

And then I found a yet simpler solution myself:

To use the hg-git Mercurial extension on Windows:

1. install the official Mercurial binaries
2. put dulwich folder
   from dulwich sources and hggit folder from hg-git sources to the
   root of library.zip in Mercurial installation folder
3. add the following to %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini:

---

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks=
hggit=
```

To have SSH support you need plink.exe from PuTTY family. After that you should add the following to Mercurial.ini:

```
[ui]
username = John Doe <foo@example.com>
ssh=d:/home/lib/dll/plink.exe -i "d:/home2/ssh-private-key.ppk"
```

When connecting to a SSH server for the first time, you should start putty.exe and try to connect using it. It will add the server key fingerprint to the registry. Otherwise plink will ask you to accept the fingerprint but it doesn't accept any input.

You can use puttygen.exe to generate private keys. Either use keys without a passphrase or use Pageant.exe ssh authentication agent.

Comment: I'm clueless with Python, so all the other methods I looked at I either totally failed at, or didn't attempt. This one got it sorted, no problem. Thanks!

Comment: In the wake of bitbucket dropping mercurial support recently, this is more relevant than ever and worked for me!

Comment: I'm glad it still works after 8 years of potential code rot.

Answer (score 8):

If you can install TortoiseHg, it includes dulwich and other requirements.

Comment: @David did you install other Mercurial executable? Please make sure your "hg" command points TortoiseHg's Mercurial executable. or try TortoiseHg 1.0.4.

Comment: This worked for me, following the instructions [here](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/1.0/nonhg.html#hg-git-git)

Answer (score 4):

Try following configuration (change to your path), which works for me:

```
[extensions]
; hg-git extention
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit = C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\hg_git-0.2.1-py2.6.egg\hggit
```

In my case when I have empty value for `hggit =`, I get the same error as you do in this case. But I can `import dulwich` without problem in python shell, so you should check your `easy-install.pth` (as pointed out by David) if it contains `dulwich-0.5.0-py2.5.egg`.
I did install pure version of `dulwich` as well.

Comment: Do I need to extract the egg for that to work? In my site-packages directory, I have that .egg file, but I do not have a directory named hg_git-0.2.1-py2.6.egg. Are you referencing hggit within the unexpanded egg file?

Comment: I do not have the egg file, and if I remember correctly the .egg file did not work properly on my machine. Then I installed using `-Z` parameter of `easy_install` in order to extract it during the installation. The same applies for `dulwich`. Hope it helps you.

Comment: This worked for me with Tortoise 1.0.3 Hg 1.5.3 installed.  Make sure you use the -Z when you easy_install hg-git, and correct the hggit path above to whatever version it ends up downloading

Answer (score 1):

I got this error as well even after downloading the latest Tortoisehg and making sure the hggit plugin was installed as well as my .ini & hgrc files had the right entry to enable hggit.

Turns out my problem was that I had both mercurial and tortoisehg in my path. So when I ran any hg commands, it was using the hg.exe in mercurial folder as opposed to the hg.exe in the torsoisehg directory.

This makes sense but my mercurial installation did not have the plug ins. My fix was to remove mercurial from my path so hg commands go through the tortoisehg directory since it has hg completely bundled. Note however, the recommended option might be to upgrade mercurual to a version that has the plugins that one needs but this is what worked for me. I tried replacing the library.zip in mercurial with the one in tortoisehg and this worked but it led to other errors as one would imagine.

@techtonik's answer led me down this road for which I am grateful.

Recap: verify which hg exe is running your hg commands by checking your path because that hg.exe does not find the plugins for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem today when installing the latest TortoiseHg.

Get the latest python 2.7 (I used 2.7.16) setup on your system, you probably have this already.
Get a command window and go to the c:\Python27 folder
To run pip use Scripts\pip or easy_install use Scripts\easy_install
Try pip -V to make sure you get the 2.7 version and not some 3.X version

Wrong:

```
c:\Python27>pip -V
pip 20.2.4 from c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

Right:

```
c:\Python27>Scripts\pip -V
pip 20.2.4 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)
```

If dulwich or hg-git are installed already

```
Scripts\pip uninstall dulwich
Scripts\pip uninstall hg-git
```

Install hg-git

```
Scripts\easy_install install hg-git
```

You should now have two folders

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\dulwich-0.19.16-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\dulwich
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\hg_git-0.9.0-py2.7.egg\hggit
```

It will only work if Dulwich is version 0.19.16 (less than 0.20.x)

Copy these folders (dulwich and hggit) into the zip-file
C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\library.zip

[folder in zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hgeD.png)

Comment: In my case, `pip install hg-git` (not `hggit`) was sufficient to get `hg-git` and all dependencies (`dulwich`, `certifi` and `urllib3`) installed in the `site_packages` folder. Copying them into `library.zip` indeed works.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Until you get `import dulwich` to work, `hggit` won't work. Check that the `dulwich` egg file is in your `easy-install.pth` file under `site-packages`.

For further debugging you can try ask `pkg_resources` about it:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.require("dulwich")
```

Comment: This line is in my easy-install.pth file:
/c/Python25/lib/site-packages/dulwich-0.5.0-py2.5.egg

Comment: I ran the pkg_resources command and put the results in the question above. Now what?

Comment: I can reproduce your exact result by easy_installing dulwich and removing it from easy-install.pth
Did you manually edit the path in your easy-install - the /c/Python25 looks wrong - I'd replace that with a straight dulwich-0.5.0-py2.5.egg
Or even better, remove the line and re-run easy_install dulwich

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too with dulwich.errors.  Instead of installing everything from scratch.  I just copied dulwich from my default site-packages to the mercurial site-packages.  worked with no problems.

Comment: This will work, but it means you won't be compiling the C extensions. Dulwich (and thus hg-git) will use the pure python implementation and thus be (significantly) slower.

Answer (score 0):

Based on techtonik's [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2733516/1236781) of the reason for the failing import of `dulwich.errors`, I found a solution which appears simpler to me than the already proposed ones:

On the [Mercurial download page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads/) there is offered

> Mercurial `<x.y.z>` for Python 2.7 on Windows x86 (source install)

and

> Mercurial `<x.y.z>` for Python 2.7 on Windows x64 (source install)

as .EXE files which **install Mercurial as a Python module** into an existing Python 2.7 (x86 or x64) installation.

If hg-git and dulwich have been installed to this Python installation as well, the import errors should vanish.

If you are not sure what to do now, I hope this step-by-step explanation helps:

## Prerequisites

- Python 2.7 is installed
- `<python 2.7 install dir>` and `<python 2.7 install dir>\Scripts` are in the `PATH` environment variable
- hg-git (and dulwich) have been installed into this Python installation via the instructions from [here](http://hg-git.github.io)

## Steps

1. Deinstall any existing Mercurial installation
2. Download and install one of the above-quoted EXE files, depending on whether your Python 2.7 installation is 32bit or 64bit (If you get a "Python 2.7 cannot be found in registry" error, you probably need the other one.)

Now `hg clone <some git repo>` should work on the console.

Answer (score 0):

**After a long research I finally managed to setup hggit properly.**
*What I have done:*

1. I have installed the newest version of TortoiseHg (in my case *Version 5.9.1*)
   This official version (automatically) contains *Python-2.7.18* (According to Help/About)
2. Download dulwich: `cd C:\dulwich`, `git clone https://github.com/dulwich/dulwich.git .`
3. TortoiseHg uses Python 2.7, dulwich doesn't support this (old) Python version anymore. We have to go back to an older version of dulwich (<0.20)
   `git reset --hard c6993451a745d313f61e5d080b9f9d8611a8d7f4`
4. The subfolder `C:\dulwich\dulwich` has to be copied inside the zip file
    `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\library.zip` so that there is a path
    `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\library.zip\dulwich`
   **This can be done by the following commands:**
   a) Extract the currenty content of TortoiseHg's library
   `md "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\ExtractedLibrary"`
   `tar -xf "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\library.zip" -C "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\ExtractedLibrary"`
   b) Copy dulwich files into directory
   `xcopy C:\dulwich\dulwich "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\ExtractedLibrary\dulwich\"`
   c) Save old library.zip and create new library.zip
   `ren "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\library.zip" library_old.zip`
   `cd "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\ExtractedLibrary"`
   `tar -acf "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\library.zip" *.*`
   d) Cleanup
   `cd ..`
   `rd /q /s "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib\ExtractedLibrary"`
   `rd /q /s C:\dulwich`
5. Download hg-git: `cd C:\hg-git`, `hg clone https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git .`
6. The current version of hg-git also does not support Python 2.7 anymore. We have to go back to the last working version 0.9.0 (=revision 1320 in TortoiseHg):
   `hg update 6d7d6f174df8`
7. Create a new empty repository which will be "connected" to a remote git repository
   `cd C:\MyLocalHgRepoWhichIsConnectedToGit`, `hg init`
8. Create a textfile `C:\MyLocalHgRepoWhichIsConnectedToGit\.hg\hgrc` with the following content:

> ```
> [paths]
> default = C:\ConnectedGitRepoForPushAndPull
>
> [extensions]
> hgext.bookmarks = 
> hggit = C:\hg-git\hggit
> ```

**Remark:** Alternatively you can also copy the folder C:\hg-git\hggit inside library.zip and leave the path in the hgrc file empty. Indeed this is my favourite way. Do it the same way as I have explained under step 4 with dulwich.

That's it. Now the Mercurial Repo is linked to the Git Repo
and you can execute  `hg pull` or `hg push` inside the Hg Repo.

---

---

If you don't want to read all my explanations you can simply use this batch file and execute it:

**hggit.bat**

```
@echo off
rem Installation von dulwich+hggit für TortoiseHg
rem Michael Hutter, 22.09.2021
rem https://stackoverflow.com/a/69279657/9134997

if "%1"=="install" goto install
if "%1"=="clonegitrepo" goto clonegitrepo
echo Syntax:
echo %0 install (installiert dulwich und hggit in TortoiseHg)
echo %0 clonegitrepo C:\HgRepoToCreate C:\GitRepoToClone (Klonen eines Git-Repos in ein Hg-Repo)
pause
goto ende


:install
set LibraryPath=C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\lib
set TempPathDulwich=C:\Temp\dulwich
set TempPathHggit=C:\Temp\hg-git

if not exist "%LibraryPath%\library.zip" (
echo Die Datei %LibraryPath%\library.zip existiert nicht!
pause
goto Ende
)

rem Installation von dulwich
md %TempPathDulwich%
cd %TempPathDulwich%
git clone https://github.com/dulwich/dulwich.git .
git reset --hard c6993451a745d313f61e5d080b9f9d8611a8d7f4
pause

rem Installation von hg-git
md %TempPathHggit%
cd %TempPathHggit%
hg clone https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git .
hg update 6d7d6f174df8
pause

rem dulwich und hggit in library.zip aufnehmen
md "%LibraryPath%\ExtractedLibrary"
tar -xf "%LibraryPath%\library.zip" -C "%LibraryPath%\ExtractedLibrary"
xcopy %TempPathDulwich%\dulwich "%LibraryPath%\ExtractedLibrary\dulwich\"
xcopy %TempPathHggit%\hggit "%LibraryPath%\ExtractedLibrary\hggit\"
ren "%LibraryPath%\library.zip" library_old.zip
if exist "%LibraryPath%\library.zip" del "%LibraryPath%\library.zip"
cd "%LibraryPath%\ExtractedLibrary"
tar -acf "%LibraryPath%\library.zip" *.*

rem Aufräumen
cd ..
rd /q /s "%LibraryPath%\ExtractedLibrary"
rd /q /s %TempPathDulwich%
rd /q /s %TempPathHggit%
pause
goto ende


:clonegitrepo
rem Klonen eines Git-Repos in ein lokales Hg-Repo
echo Erstelle neues HgRepo %2
md %2
cd %2
if not exist %2 (
echo "Fehler: %2 existiert nicht!"
pause
goto ende
)
hg init
echo [paths] > .hg\hgrc
echo default = %3 >> .hg\hgrc
echo. >> .hg\hgrc
echo [extensions] >> .hg\hgrc
echo hgext.bookmarks = >> .hg\hgrc
echo hggit = >> .hg\hgrc
hg pull
hg update
pause

:ende
```

Answer (score -2):

> sudo apt-get install python-dev # Dam you dependency!
>
> sudo easy_install dulwich

Success!