# How do I install the hg-git plugin on Debian Stretch?

Tags: easy-install, python-packaging, mercurial-extension, hg-git, debian-stretch

Debian Jessie, as well as sid, have a `mercurial-git` package which contains the `hg-git` plugin. However, this package was [(auto-)removed from Debian Stretch to to a release-critical bug](https://tracker.debian.org/news/961900/hg-git-removed-from-testing/).

But - I need it installed and running. Surely this should be possible, right?

Well, I followed the installation instructions on the [plugin page](https://hg-git.github.io/):

- I ran `apt-get install python-setuptools python-setuptools-git python4-setuptools python3-setuptools-git`
- I ran `easy_install hg-git` and it seemed to work

But still, when I run various mercurial operations I get, as the first line, the error message:

```
*** failed to import extension hgext.git: No module named git
```

(regardless of whether I'm doing anything git-related or not.)

My questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. What do I need to do in order to make the error message go away while having hggit working?

Now,

[How do I correctly install dulwich to get hg-git working on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360944/how-do-i-correctly-install-dulwich-to-get-hg-git-working-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, that critical bug doesn't manifest always (and perhaps only under very specific circumstances), so you can try installing the [Debian sid version of the `mercurial-git` package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/mercurial-git) (that is, version 0.8.11-1 at the time of writing). There's a SuperUser question about how to do this:

https://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-install-a-single-package-from-debian-sid-or-debian-testing

my personal opinion in this case is to simply install the .deb file, which you can get from [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/mercurial-git/download) (it's not platform-specific; at the link you'll need to choose a mirror.) That makes the error message go away, at least assuming you have:

```
[extensions]
hgext.bookmarks =
hggit =
```

in your `~/.hgrc` file.